# Converting $\mathbb{C}$ linear tranformation with determinant $a+bi$ into an $\mathbb{R}$-linear transformation with determinant $a^2+b^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, complex-numbers

> Let $V=\mathbb{C}^2$. Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ denote a $\mathbb{C}$ linear tranformation with determinant $a+bi$, $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that if we regard $V$ as a $4-$dimentional real vector space, the determinant of $T$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-linear transformation of this space is $a^2+b^2$.

Let $\left[ \begin{array}{c} z_1 \\ z_2 \end{array} \right] = \begin{bmatrix} u_{11} & u_{12} \\ u_{21} & u_{22} \end{bmatrix} \times \left[ \begin{array}{c} z_1 \\ z_2 \end{array} \right]$ be the transformation where det$\begin{bmatrix} u_{11} & u_{12} \\ u_{21} & u_{22} \end{bmatrix} =a+bi$. Then I was going to expand this by writing each complex no. $z_j$'s and $u_{ij}$'s in the form $x+iy$ where $x,y$ real. Then it looked like so messy. Is there a simple way of solving this? Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to think in terms of block-matrices.  You should find $T:V_{\Bbb R} \to V_{\Bbb R}$ to be given by
$$
\pmatrix{
\pmatrix{a_1\\b_1}\\
\pmatrix{a_2\\b_2}
}
\mapsto
\pmatrix{
\pmatrix{a_{11} & -b_{11}\\b_{11} & a_{11}} & 
\pmatrix{a_{12} & -b_{12}\\b_{12} & a_{12}} \\
\pmatrix{a_{21} & -b_{21}\\b_{21} & a_{21}} &
\pmatrix{a_{22} & -b_{22}\\b_{22} & a_{22}}
}
\pmatrix{
\pmatrix{a_1\\b_1}\\
\pmatrix{a_2\\b_2}
}
$$
Where $z_i = a_i + b_i$ and $u_{ij} = a_{ij} + b_{ij}$.

You can then find the determinant of the block matrix using the fact that each pair of "block-entries" commutes.